# ngModel is not accessible from within a directive

Tags: angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-model

Please give me some slack, this is my first post as I'm pretty new to angular. 
I'm trying to implement a directive that will verify if an account name is exist.

While I've been using this kind of directive (and used it for several purposes), I've encounter with a showstopper to my excitement =( .

The directive is being triggered from an input tag that holds an ngModel. 
This is my partial directive :

```
app.directive('organizationValidate', function (dataFactory) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
        $ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
            $ctrl.$setValidity('organizationValidate', true);
            if ($ctrl.$valid) {
                $ctrl.$setValidity('checkingOrganization', false);
                console.log("Got the Direc");
```

and this is my HTML input :

```
<input type="text" data-organization-validate class="form-control" ng-model="newOrg.OrganizationName">
```

while trying to access to $scope.newOrg.OrganizationName from within the directive I got newOrg undefined ... :(

Any advise ?

Thanks !

Comment: where do you define the `newOrg` object?

Comment: what controller? you have partial code for a directive which uses ngModel as a controller, but no custom controller. I'd expect to see something like `$scope.newOrg = { ... }`

Comment: Pardon for my ignorance, I must say I'm a bit confused here. I've declared the 'newOrg' object in my work controller. My intention in this directive to bind between the 'newOrg' value (from the input tag) to my directive.